# Task.WhenAll with different results - execute the Tasks in parallel C#

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, parallel-processing

My question really is, is there a technical reason why you should or not use Task.WhenAll()? Is it just a preference when I like these 2 tasks to run parallel. Or just using two await tasks, instead of WhenAll.

And may I know what is the different between

```
var aTask = aService.GetAContentAsync(request.Language);

var bTask = bService.GetBContentAsync(request.Language);

await Task.WhenAll(aTask, bTask);

var aResponse = aTask.Result;
var bResponse = bTask.Result;

var response = new Content
{
   Title = aResponse ,
   Details = bResponse 
};
```

And

```
var aTask = aService.GetAContentAsync(request.Language);

var bTask = bService.GetBContentAsync(request.Language);

await Task.WhenAll(aTask, bTask);

var aResponse = await aTask;
var bResponse = await bTask;

var response = new Content
{
   Title = aResponse ,
   Details = bResponse 
};
```

Or better to do as below

```
var aTask = aService.GetAContentAsync(request.Language);

var bTask = bService.GetBContentAsync(request.Language);

var allTasks = await Task.WhenAll(aTask, bTask);

var aResponse = allTasks[0];
var bResponse = allTasks[1];

var response = new Content
{
   Title = aResponse ,
   Details = bResponse 
};
```

Understand the different for code above and which is better

Comment: All of your examples do use `WhenAll`. So, I am a little confused. Is it about "to use WhenAll or not to use WhenAll" or something different?

Comment: concurrent != parallel

Comment: ... != asynchronous

Comment: IMHO it's best to avoid using `Result` even if it's technically safe after the `WhenAll`.

Answer (score 0):

`Task.WhenAll` already returns the results in an array, and you seem to know this from your third example. Why would you await a second time to get them again?

Also, you cannot await `ValueTask`s a second time, [it is explicitly mentioned by the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1?view=net-7.0). So at best you're doing very inefficient work and at worst you're corrupting your task workflow.

Comment: `Task.WhenAll` only returns an array when the return type of each task is the same.